# Looping inside a beam transform. Process sequentially using Apache Beam

Tags: java, apache-flink, apache-beam

I am creating a beam pipeline to do batch processing of data bundles. The pipeline reads records using CassandraIO. I want to process the data in batches of 30 min then group/stitch 30 min data and write it to another table.
I have 300 bundles for each employee and I need to process at least process 50 employees using the limited resources(~2Gi).
But currently the heap usage is very high so that I am only able to process 1 employee(with ~4Gi). if I give more data I am getting Out of memory/Heap errors.

Is their a way to process 1 employee at a time. Like a loop so that I can process all employees sequentially with my ~2Gi

below is my sample code

```
Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);
 dataToWritetoDb = p.apply(CassandraIO.<LevelOneInputEntity>read()
                    .withHosts(Arrays.asList("127.0.0.1")).withPort(9042).withKeyspace("beam")
                    .withTable("LevelOneInputEntity").withEntity(LevelOneInputEntity.class).withConnectTimeout(1000)
                    .withReadTimeout(5000).withCoder(SerializableCoder.of(LevelOneInputEntity.class)))
.apply(ParDo.of(new ApplyTimeStampDoFnFunction()))
.apply(Window.<EntityClass>into(FixedWindows.of(Duration.standardMinutes(30)))
.apply("Group and create keyvalue bundles",ParDo.of(new BundleKVDoFn(mapper)))
```

Is there a way to implement the below kind of logic, so that the pipeline will run for each employee once?

```
  Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);
    
    for (String employeeId : employeelist) {
        sql = "select * from LevelOneInputEntity where employeeId = "+employeeId;
        dataToWritetoDb =  p.apply(CassandraIO.<LevelOneInputEntity>read()
                            .withHosts(Arrays.asList("127.0.0.1")).withPort(9042).withKeyspace("beam")
                            .withTable("LevelOneInputEntity").withEntity(LevelOneInputEntity.class).withConnectTimeout(1000).withQuery(sql)
                            .withReadTimeout(5000).withCoder(SerializableCoder.of(LevelOneInputEntity.class)))
        .apply(ParDo.of(new ApplyTimeStampDoFnFunction()))
        .apply(Window.<EntityClass>into(FixedWindows.of(Duration.standardMinutes(30)))
        .apply("Group and create keyvalue bundles",ParDo.of(new BundleKVDoFn(mapper)))
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Beam doesn't have a built-in way to do this, but you can add locking in your expensive DoFn that only allows one element to be processed at once.  Something like

```
class ExpensiveDoFn extends DoFn<Input, Output> {
  private static Lock lock;
  @ProcessElement
  public void Process(@Element Input input) {
    lock.lock();
    // Do memory-intensive processing here.
    lock.unlock()
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you could try looking at a heap dump from your program to see if you can optimize the memory usage